# CSS nth-of-type mistery

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've the problem below.

```
small:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}
small:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: green;
}
small:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: blue;
}
```

The **expected working** is to set the first small's color to red, the second's to green and the third's blue. Does nth-of-type work only on siblings? :(

Thanks!
Adam

https://jsfiddle.net/bh3qz3d8

Comment: Yes, they need to be under the same parent. In your fiddle, each `small` is the first of its type under its own parent. You'd need to select the appropriate `li` and then style the `small` under that `li`. (like `li:nth-of-type(2) small {color: red}` for example).

Comment: Logically `small` element in your case is always the first child of parent

Comment: Only works for siblings. See your updated fiddle for a demo of when it would work. http://jsfiddle.net/bh3qz3d8/1/

Comment: To get expected result, you can use nth-of-type, but on parent tag - li, in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/bh3qz3d8/2/

Comment: Yeah :( as I thought.. it's a nonsense.. and as I experienced, nth-of-type ignores classnames at all.. so suppose there is 3 li-s and the last one have class="img".. then li.img:nth-of-type(1) just selects the first li ... :/ that's a logic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by Harry and Mr. Alien, the `small` is always the first of it's type inside the list-items.

So you'll need to change your selector.

Basicly your list has a list item without `img` and `small`, and a list item with `img` and `small`, and so on.

So changing your CSS to this, should do the trick:

```
li:nth-of-type(2) small {
    color: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(4) small {
    color: green;
}
li:nth-of-type(6) small {
    color: blue;
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bh3qz3d8/3/)

Comment: This is cool, but not what I need. No problem, CSS4 will solve my problem! Thx